# Plugin jQuery com gatilho em evento click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugin

## Plugin jQuery:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({
        meuPlugin: function(){
            $('body').on('click', this, function( e ){
                console.log( $(this).attr('href') );
                return false;
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

## Seletor no HTML:

```
<a href="um_link_qualquer.php" id="link_teste">Meu link</a>
```

## Chamada do Plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link_teste').meuPlugin();
});
```

## Problema:

`$(this).attr('href')` está fazendo referência ao `body`, não ao `$('#link_teste')` na chamada do plugin.

• Minha primeira tentativa foi alterar:

`$('body').on('click', this, function( e ){` para `this.on('click', function() {`

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({
        meuPlugin: function(){
            //$('body').on('click', this, function( e ){
            this.on('click', function() {
                console.log( $(this).attr('href') );
                return false;
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

PS: Funcionou, mas não 100%. Acontece que se eu atribuir o plugin à um elemento que será carregado posteriormente via ajax, o click não vai chamar o plugin.

• Tentei também com o `e.target`, a única diferença é que ao invés de retornar o `body`, **retorna o elemento clicado**, seja lá qual for.

• Esta é uma outra tentativa:

```
// plugin
$.fn.extend({
    meuPlugin: function () {
        console.log( this.attr('href') );
        return false;
    }
});
// chamada do plugin no elemento #link_teste
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#link_teste', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.target).meuPlugin();
    });
});
```

Funciona exatamente como preciso, porém a chamada do plugin ficou muito "suja". Preciso de algo mais preciso e limpo como já mencionado:

```
$('#link_teste').meuPlugin();
```

## Objetivo:

Preciso dos atributos de `#link_teste` referenciando-o dentro do plugin, tais como `href`, `action`, `method`, etc e que seja compatível com as chamadas do *ajax*:

```
$('#link_teste').meuPlugin();
```

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembre-se que no [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) deve-se manter a hierarquia dos elementos. O elemento-pai, delega a função para seus descendentes que correspondem ao seletor.

Nesse caso, o `<body>` está delegando aos elementos `<a>` que tenham o ID correspondente.

Ex.:

```js
$.fn.extend({
  meuPlugin: function () {
    let id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    
    $('body').on('click', id, function () {
      console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    });
  }
});

$(function () {
  $('#link_teste').meuPlugin();
  $('#outro_link').meuPlugin();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link_teste">Link qualquer</a>
<br><br>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" id="outro_link">Outro link qualquer</a>
<br><br>
<button type="button">Clique aqui para testar se irá ativar</button>
```

(Clique em "executar" e verifique a saída do *console*)

Comment: Então, o problema é q o this se refere ao body, logo o plugin é chamado ao clicar em qualquer elemento no site.

Comment: Alterei o trecho de código, por favor, dá uma olhada.

Comment: `this` não se refere ao `<body>`, se refere ao retorno de elemento(s) do seletor `$('a')`. Na verdade o problema que informou ocorre sim, mas pelo que percebi é no seletor `$('body').on('click', ...)` lá dentro do escopo do *plugin*, pois esse seletor vai adicionar um *event handler* no `<body>` todo.

Comment: Exatamente. Vou editar a pergunta com um outro experimento que fiz e funcionou, mas também não é exatamente o que eu preciso.

Comment: Na verdade, mais especificamente o problema era no `this` passado para o método `on()` aqui: `$('body').on('click', this, ...)`. Editei a resposta, por favor, verifique se é dessa forma que está procurando. Adicionei o ID no lugar do `this`, pois estávamos passando um objeto, porém o parâmetro aceita somente *string*: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Só faltou `preventDefault()`, mas eu add aqui. Vlw irmão! :D

Comment: Tranquilo, brother! Tamo junto!